# How can I write a voice command that restarts Dragon NaturallySpeaking without using an external program?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

By writing a voice command I do not mean writing my own program but using Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting. I know I could write a small program that takes care of killing + restarting Dragon (e.g. using AHK), which I could call through a voice command by writing a Dragon voice command that simply calls this program. However, if possible (I don't know if it's the case here), I'd prefer to avoid having voice commands that rely on an external program.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I have posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-a-voice-command-that-restarts-Dragon-NaturallySpeaking

Comment: I'm still interested in this question, as I still use dragon.